# C RSA key generation program

Tags: c, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to hone my skills in C as well as get a better understanding of RSA, so I took it upon myself to try and make my own generator. I've generated both base prime numbers, p and q, calculated the value o = (p-1) * (q-1). These are working correctly. The next steps is where I'm having issues. I'm pretty close, but I can't seem to find the correct way to calculate the encryption and decryption factors of the 1 mod r value. Any help for generating this would be awesome. (or just write the code yourself and i can learn off that) Plus if there's any other issues let me know!

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include"../hdr/test.h"    //fake header just to satisfy my makefile

//Receives: number that was generated in main
//Returns: 1 for false, 0 for true
//Purpose: checks if the numbers is prime and returns 1 or 0
int isPrime(int number) 
{
    if (number <= 1) 
        return 0;

    int i;
    for (i=2; i<number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) 
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/*Receives: an integer ((p-1) * (q-1))
  Returns: integer (e)
  Purpose: Generates the relatively prime number to ((p-1) * (q-1))*/
int gen_E(int o)
{
    puts("Generating E...");
    int e;
    do {e = rand() % o;} while (GCD(e, o) != 1);
    return e;
}

/*Receives: integer E and O from the main
  Returns: newly calculated integer D
  Purpose: Generates D for the private key*/
int gen_D(int e, int o)
{
puts("Generating D...");
int e = a;
int o = b;
int phin, d;
for (phin = 1; phin < o; phin ++)
    for (d = 1; d < 998001; d ++)
        if ((e * d) == (o * phin) + 1) return d;
}

/*Receives: integer E and O from main
  Returns: greatest common divisor's remainder
  Purpose: Calculate if the two numbers share a divisor.*/    
int GCD(int e, int o)
{
    int c;
    while (e != 0) {
        c = e; e = o%e; o = c;
    }
    return o;
}
int main()
{
    puts("Generating Prime P...");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int p = rand() % 1000;
    while (isPrime(p) != 1) {
        p = rand() % 1000;
    }

    puts("Generating Prime Q...");
    int q = rand() % 1000;
    while (isPrime(q) != 1) {
        q = rand() % 1000;
    }

    int n = p * q;
    int o = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    int e = gen_E(o);
    int d = gen_D(e, o);

    printf("p: %d\nq: %d\nn: %d\no: %d\ne: %d\nd: %d\n", p, q, n, o, e, d);
    printf("KU = {%d, %d}\n", e, n);
    printf("KR = {%d, %d}\n", d, n);
}
```

Comment: Now you need `<stdlib.h>` for the prototypes of `srand()`, `rand()`. But my main point still stands: **do not use a C++ compiler for C code.**

Comment: oh wow, I was using g++ and not gcc. Thanks for pointing that out, never noticed.

Comment: Note that with such tiny primes, you have a significant probability of any given message colliding with one of them (which will result in the encryption/decryption failing to work).

Answer (score 2):

You will need a function to compute GCD (greatest common divider) of two numbers. After that, choose random e such that GCD(e,o) == 1.

Of course in practice it's probably more complicated than that but for homework it's fine.